# How to recover deleted file from windows?

Tags: boot

I just changed the operating system from windows 11 to ubuntu and all my files are deleted. So how can i recover my file?

Comment: Don't do anything in your system. **Immediately** turn off and boot to a live system to prevent further data writes! Then, make a copy of your drive using `dd`. Then you can use data recovery tools on the copy. (e.g. `testdisk` and  `photorec`).

Comment: You could have copied the data to a USB before you installed Ubuntu

Comment: If you can make a USB-stick with Hiren's Boot CD ( https://www.hirensbootcd.org/ ) on it on another system, you would have some usefull (Windows)tools. But make it on another system!

Answer (score 0):

it is almost impossible to recover the files in this case because the way to format the disk of windows and ubuntu is different.
You could still try from ubuntu via TestDisk with which you go to explore the files deleted from the disk but I recommend you use it if you have a minimum of manual skills.

https://vitux.com/how-to-recover-deleted-files-in-ubuntu-through-testdisk/